# Simple mod_rewrite 301 redirect with flags, possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have approx 100 pages that are currently using the simple 301 redirect format:

```
Redirect 301 /friendly_url http://www.domain.com/new_url
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to set some flags on these, as I've set some environment specific rules to set header vars which I've applied to the more 'complex' redirects e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co(m|\.uk)$ [NC]<br />
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L,E=nocache:1]
```

The environment specific directives are as follows:

```
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=nocache<br />
Header always set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=nocache
```

So would it be possible to add:

```
Redirect 301 /friendly_url http://www.domain.com/new_url [L,E=nocache:1]
```

Can't seem to find anything on the mod_rewrite docs about the simple redirect format, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set env variable in `Redirect` directive OR when you are doing external redirect.

Use `mod_rewrite` instead without `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^friendly_url /new_url [L,NC,E=nocache:1]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply I was about to post my own answer then - came to the same conclusion - Thanks.

Comment: Quick question though - why would you use it without R ?

Comment: That is because once you do an external redirect all the environment set in previous request is lost since Apache receives a new request. If you want to carry some env across the different request then work around is use of cookies via `mod_rewrite`.